# Are there settings that must go into the IIS ApplicationHost.config file only?

Tags: iis, iis7

Are there setting that must go into ApplicationHost.config opposed to into web.config file under the IIS web server? I.e. Are there any settings not allowed in web.config, or can I move all my ApplicationHost.config settings to web.config?

There in only one site.